# Possible to have a class implementing Runnable() to have a method that uses itself for a new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Im trying to build a Task object that implements Runnable, that via a begin() method spawns a new Thread, using itself as the Runnable object in the Thread?

The generic Task object itself will have various properties, and will be added to a collection / array of similar Task objects, that when certain properties in the Task match specific criteria, that the Task will be run, itself, in its own thread. The Task object itself will be extended, such that I can make a PurgeTask class, or a CleanTask class, etc..

For example:

```
public abstract class Task implements Runnable {
static final int ABOUT_TO_RUN = 0;
static final int RUNNING = 1;
static final int DONE_RUNNING = 2;

int someProperty;
int anotherProperty;

int state = ABOUT_TO_RUN;           //lets start in a not ran state

public abstract void run();

//some other common methods I want here

public void beginTask() {
    if (this.state == ABOUT_TO_RUN) {
        this.state == RUNNING;
        new Thread(this).start();   //Here is where my question refers too
        this.state == DONE_RUNNING;
    }
}
```

And then...

```
public class CleanTask extends Task {

public CleanTask() {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //some code that does a cleaning task in a database
}
}
```

Would this be possible? Or will the problems with an abstract Runnable class using itself in a new Thread?

Comment: Awesome, thanks everyone! The idea is that CleanTask() can have a property that points to a specific table in a database, and then I can just instantiate this class for each table, for example, then call each .beginTask() method, or have it called based on the criteria

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is perfectly possible. Your `CleanTask` is already an implementation of `Runnable` for extending `Task`. A thread needs a `Runnable` as it's target, so it can actually execute the `run` method of `CleanTask`.

But try using the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) which has already implementation of such functionality.

Comment: Ahh ok, never tried working with the Executor classes, will look into that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be possible? Or will the problems with an abstract Runnable class using itself in a new Thread?

I don't see any inherent problems.  The typical Java class hierarchy is perfectly acceptable here.  So another class would instantiate a `CleanTask` and then call `beginTask()` method on that class.  Any changes to fields made by the thread that calls `beginTask()` will be seen by the new thread appropriately.

You would still need to worry about changes to the `CleanTask` instance made by *other* threads other than the one that calls `beginTask()`.  You'd also need to be careful that if two threads called `beginTask()` on the same instance of `CleanTask` that the two forked threads might be modifying the same fields in the single `CleanTask` instance.

Comment: Ahh, yes, this! And yes, I am aware of that constraint. Some of the methods are using a synchronized(obj) to ensure this :)

Answer (score 0):

This can work but really you are creating a mini thread pool which can only execute one task.  I suggest using an ExecutorService for your thread and task management.  This gives you thread reuse, better control of your thread/tasks and collection of results asynchronously.